# weblogic 12.2.1 deployment issue : CDI deployment failure

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, weblogic12c

I am getting the following exception while trying to deploy ear file in WL 12.2.1 server. The ear gets deployed without issue in Weblogic 12.1.2. Here is the error log. Being trying to resolve this for few days without any success. Any idea why this exception comes from WebLogic packages?

```
<Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure 
occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "74520344836697" for  task "0" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: > "weblogic.management.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:groovy/lang/GroovyObject"
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:groovy/lang/GroovyObject
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:95)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.activate(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:43)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:39)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.GroovyObject
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the older WLS has `groovy-all-2.x.y.jar` in its classpath.

That library can be found at any maven repository:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.4.16

You must put that library in WLS classpath or inside your ear.